# How do I execute SystemVerilog code at garbage collection?

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-dpi

I have a SystemVerilog class that encapsulates a C++ class using a chandle and the DPI. I want to be sure that the C++ class’s destructor is called when the SystemVerilog object is destroyed. As far as I can tell, this is not being done automatically and I have to manually call the C++ destructor through the DPI when I think that I no longer need the instance. Not very elegant.

Is there a way to specify that certain code should be run for a SV class at GC? Similar to a Java finalize method.

Comment: An interesting question. I've never heard of such a thing. I think you're going to have to do it manually. Or perhaps semi-automatically: could you have a thread that checks for null references and calls the destructor when it detects one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no construct similar to `finalize` within SystemVerilog. However, you can register a VPI callback (cbReclaimObj) on the handle. See section 38.36.1 of the 1800-2017 LRM.

Comment: This only works if you want to schedule some C/C++ code to run, since you can't invoke SV from VPI.

Comment: @TudorTimi I think that will be fine for what they have ask for so far.

Comment: Mentioned only as a note for others who read the answer and might think of calling SV code when an object gets reclaimed.

Comment: *Some* tools do allow mixing of VPI and DPI within certain restrictions.

Comment: You know my "dream" of being able to call any SV function (even non-DPI exported ones) from VPI to be able to build a true reflection library.